# Derivation of 4-velocity - where does this equation come from?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, velocity, coordinate-systems

I'm a student working through a special relativity book. In a chapter of the book, they are deriving each of the components of a 4-velocity vector in terms of ordinary 3-velocity.

(Here $\vec{x}$ represents all the space dimensions of an event, so for example in 3 space dimensions it could actually represent $x^2+y^2+z^2$.)

What I currently understand is that:

Each component of the 4-velocity is the derivative of its respective component in a 4-dimensional time/space vector with respect to proper time, so for instance if the 4-velocity vector is $(U^0,U^1,U^2,U^3)$ then

$$U^0=\frac{dt}{d \tau}=\frac{1}{\frac{d \tau}{dt}}$$

Proper time is invariant and defined as
$$\tau = \sqrt{t^2-\vec{x}^2}$$

However, after this, the book states that

$$d \tau = \sqrt{dt^2-d\vec{x}^2}$$

and hence

$$\frac{d \tau}{dt}=\frac{\sqrt{dt^2-d\vec{x}^2}}{dt}=\sqrt{1-\vec{v}^2}$$

directly follows from the definition of proper time.

I don't understand how you can take that definition of proper time and get  $$d \tau = \sqrt{dt^2-d\vec{x}^2}$$ from it.

When taking the derivative of $\tau$ with respect to $t$ I don't see how you can get an expression with second order differentials inside the square root. The only way I can think of to interpret this is to say that a small change in $\tau$ corresponds to a small change in both $t$ and $\vec{x}$, but this doesn't seem remotely rigorous at all.

Can someone help explain where this comes from?

Comment: Is that really how the book defined proper time?

Comment: *"$\vec{x}$ represents all the space dimensions of an event, so for example in 3 space dimensions it could actually represent $x^2+y^2+z^2$."* This isn't right. The sum of the squared components is the square of magnitude of $\vec{x}$ which is written $|\vec{x}|^2$. The symbol with the arrow on it ($\vec{x}$) represents the vector. To write it in terms of components you use a compact notation like $(x, y, z)$ or unit vectors like $x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k}$. But it is important to keep in mind that the magnitude is not the vector, just the size of the vector (without direction information).

Comment: @G.Smith The book defined it by trying to introduce the concept of a quantity that is the same in any two reference frames along the x axis $(x,t)$ and $x',t'$ by showing that $t^2-x^2$ and $t'^2-x'^2$ were the same when substituted into the Lorentz transformation equations for one dimension, and then trying to generalise it by showing $t^2-\vec{x}^2$ was invariant under coordinate rotations.  A quick internet search shows a more rigorous definition - is the book just explaining things very badly?

Comment: Possibly. When the book showed that combination to be invariant, did it then define it as the proper time $\tau$? If so, it should not have.

Comment: @G.Smith Yes, it defined proper time in that way. Is the definition at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time#Mathematical_formalism any better? Is it this commonplace to see infinitesimals used in physics like they are in this link?

Comment: Wikipedia is better. It is common to see infinitesimals like that. The geometrical idea is that proper time measured by an object is the arc length in spacetime along its world-line.

Comment: One common approach, rather than starting with differentials, is to define the proper time interval $\Delta\tau$ *between two events in spaceetime with finite timelike separation*  as $$(\Delta \tau)^2 = (c \Delta t)^2 - (\Delta x)^2 - (\Delta y)^2 - (\Delta z)^2,$$ after showing that this is invariant under Lorentz (or Poincare) transformations. Then going to the differential form is obvious. The point is that proper time is not a number *at* each point in spacetime, as in your book's first definition. It is a number measuring the interval *between* timelike-separated points in spacetime.

Comment: @G.Smith I think I see what the issue was - that definition in the book was implicitly referring to the interval between the event and some arbitrary origin.

Comment: @G.Smith Even though the definition in the book was somewhat questionable, how can you go from $\tau = \sqrt{t^2-\vec{x}^2}$  to $d \tau = \sqrt{dt^2-d\vec{x}^2}$?

Comment: Which book is this?

Comment: You can’t get from one to the other, which is why you can’t define $\tau$ that way and then expect to take its differential to get what everyone agrees is $d\tau$. You have to start by thinking about deltas.

Comment: @Brick Special Relativity and Classical Field Theory